# Adding 500+ Twitter users to Twitter Lists w/ buggy Twitter API

Tags: ruby, twitter

I have about 1,700 Twitter screen names I like to add to a Twitter List. As Twitter limits the number of users to 500 per List I'll need 4 Twitter Lists.

I'm using the Twitter gem. Here's what I came up with (fake values):

```
client = Twitter::Client.new({ oauth_token: access_token, oauth_token_secret: access_secret })

all_twitter_accounts = ['screen_name_1', 'screen_name_2', '...', 'screen_name_1700']

list_1_id = 12
list_2_id = 34
list_3_id = 56
list_4_id = 78 

client.list_add_members(list_1_id, all_twitter_accounts[0...499])
client.list_add_members(list_2_id, all_twitter_accounts[500...999])
client.list_add_members(list_3_id, all_twitter_accounts[1000...1499])
client.list_add_members(list_4_id, all_twitter_accounts[1500...1999])
```

However, there's two problems with this approach:

1. The `all_twitter_accounts` array has some non-existing screen names in them. `list_add_members` just skips those, but it means the lists won't fill up to 500. So I either need a way to first sanitize `all_twitter_accounts` or automate the switching to the next List when the current one has really hit its limit of 500.
2. The Twitter API [appears to be somewhat buggy](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/14045#comment-form).
   I haven't got the mentioned workaround to work.

Anyway to make this work? I only need to do this once so any other solution is welcome as well.

Comment: Is this for spam bot logic?

Comment: No. I write about internet startups (on their request). I would like to create Twitter lists of all startups I have written about so far. Need to import a backlog of 1,700 accounts. After that I'll add new startups one by one.